# Angular 2 add user key with firebases

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

Hi guys I need some help I am new in this new world of angular, I have a databases in firebases I uses de angularfire2 for make the connection with the angular 2, I have the isteme user login and the databases.

```
mydatbases 

  --users
     -- I want here add the real key give to me my firebases auth sistem ?
     -- email
     -- role
```

I use some like this for set the items

```
this.fa.object('/user').set({

  email: userEmail,
  role: 'admin'

});
```

I dont know if I have to use this hay or push like a list ?
Some one can help me thanks ?

Comment: first you need to check user is already in there, if user present you can use `.update` if not you can use `.push` on a `FirebaseListObservable`

Comment: Thanks but how I can make the push and the pass the value key as the uid is coming from auth sistem firebases ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I find,
I just pass the uid ask atribute like this

```
this.fa.object('/user/'+ uid).update({

      email: userEmail,
      role: 'admin'

  });
```

and eureka is work.